# Angular: Prevent multiple requests from pipes using same service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to build a module that would allow Angular to use Fluent for translations. I created a service and a pipe that allow using Fluent in any Angular project. As soon as the first pipe is executed the service checks if the translaiton file is already cached and downloads it otherwise.

https://gitlab.com/tobias47n9e/angular-fluent/blob/master/angular-fluent/src/lib/angular-fluent.service.ts#L66

```ts
private fetchTranslationsAndResolveKey(
    key: string,
    options: any,
    locale: string,
): Observable<string> {
    return this.http
        .get(`assets/i18n/${locale}.ftl`, { responseType: 'text' })
        .pipe(
            map((content: string) => {
                this.translationsMap[locale] = content;
                this.fetchingFile = false;
                return this.resolveKey(key, options, locale);
            }),
            concatAll(),
        );
}
```

But it looks like every pipe is getting its own copy of this observable chain or something is not working with waiting on this first request. Is there a good pattern to avoid downloading the translation file multiple times?

Pipe:

```ts
@Pipe({
name: 'fluent',
pure: false,
})
export class FluentPipe implements PipeTransform {
locale: BehaviorSubject<string>;

constructor(private fluentService: AngularFluentService) {}

transform(key: string, args?: any): Observable<string> {
    if (!this.locale) {
        this.locale = this.fluentService.locale;
        this.locale.subscribe(locale => {
            if (locale) {
                return this.fluentService.translate(
                    key,
                    args,
                    getLocale(args),
                );
            }
        });
    }

    return this.fluentService.translate(key, args, getLocale(args));
}
}
```

Current solution that keeps the state in the service:

- https://gitlab.com/tobias47n9e/angular-fluent/blob/master/angular-fluent/src/lib/angular-fluent.service.ts#L30
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-fluent

Comment: Would the [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator work here?

Comment: @phix Thanks for the suggestion. I tried some variants of shareReplay, but I haven't figured it out yet

Answer (score 0):

I am not very much sure how this plug-in works but what I think you need is the `as` transformation operator

You can have the root node in your template use the async pipe which can assign the result to a variable which can be used within the template once ready as

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data | custPipeReturningObservable$ | async as num">
    {{num}}
</ng-container>
```

Mode details in the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-with-custom-pipe where I have tried to chain a custom pipe returning an observable with the async pipe

Answer (score 0):

The `AngularFluentService` maintains a map (`translationsMap:12`) of the translations for a given locale that you pass to `AngularFluentService::translate`. If the map doesn't contain the locale it will make a http request but all subsequent calls to `translate` with the same locale will retrieve the translation from the map instead without making the request. So all you should need to do in the pipe is the following:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'fluent'
})
export class FluentPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private fluentService: AngularFluentService) {
  }

  transform(key: string, args?: any): Observable<string> {
    return this.fluentService.translate(key, args, getLocale(args));
  }
}
```

Comment: If I do that I just get the same number of request and loose the updating of the strings when the locale changes. The pipes are probably all independent objects?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to commit a translation file to your GitLab project so I can test another solution?